# Slide div from bottom on button click and push the screen up

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

This is a mobile website. I have a "More" button at the bottom of the page which when clicked should bring up the additional footer links. Now, the problem is that if i use jQuery's `slideToggle` it displays the menu, the page height increases but it remains hidden, meaning I have to scroll the screen to view it. But when I press the button again, it hides the menu and gives the required effect.

My code is:

**HTML**

```
<div class="footer-more" style="text-align:center;"><button class="footer-more-btn">More +</button></div>

<div class="bottom-nav-container">
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" id="trackOrder">Track Your Order</a></li>
            <li><a href="/faqs">FAQs</a></li>
            <li><a href="/mobile-about-us">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="/t-and-c">Terms</a></li>
            <li><a href="/privacy">Privacy</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>  
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.bottom-nav-container{
    margin-top:20px;
    width:100%;
    height:200px;
    border-top:1px solid #e8e5e5;
    display:none;
}

.bottom-nav-container ul{
    background: #f9f9f9;
}

.bottom-nav-container ul li{

}

.bottom-nav-container ul li a{
    display: block;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: #645d54 !important;
    text-shadow: 0 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0);
    padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom:1px solid #e8e5e5;
}
```

**JS**

```
$pop = jQuery.noConflict();
$pop(".footer-more-btn, .close-footer").click(function(){

  $pop(".bottom-nav-container").slideToggle();

});
```

Comment: Expanding the element won't change the browser's size.  What do you mean by "gives the desired effect"?

Comment: @jmargolisvt "Desired Effect" means it shows the transition + slide effect when it is already visible and toggled with the button and the screen pushes down. But when it is toggled to be visible, it doesn't push the screen up.